# Is this excercise doable without a computer? Triangular Number with n divisors

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

> The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural
>   numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7
>   = 28. The first ten terms would be:
>
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
>
> Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
>
> ```
>  1: 1
>  3: 1,3
>  6: 1,2,3,6
> 10: 1,2,5,10
> 15: 1,3,5,15
> 21: 1,3,7,21
> 28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
> ```
>
> We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five
>   divisors.
>
> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five
>   hundred divisors?

from https://projecteuler.net/problem=12

$n$th triangular number=$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

(little Gauss)

Algorithm to find number of divisors:

from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/total-number-divisors-given-number/

```
# Python3 program for finding  
# number of divisor 

# program for finding  
# no. of divisors 
def divCount(n): 

    # sieve method for 
    # prime calculation 
    hh = [1] * (n + 1); 

    p=2; 
    while((p * p) < n): 
        if (hh[p] == 1): 
            for i in range((p * 2),n,p): 
                hh[i] = 0; 
        p+=1; 

    # Traversing through  
    # all prime numbers 
    total = 1; 
    for p in range(2,n+1): 
        if (hh[p] == 1): 

            # calculate number of divisor 
            # with formula total div =  
            # (p1+1) * (p2+1) *.....* (pn+1) 
            # where n = (a1^p1)*(a2^p2)....  
            # *(an^pn) ai being prime divisor 
            # for n and pi are their respective  
            # power in factorization 
            count = 0; 
            if (n % p == 0): 
                while (n % p == 0): 
                    n = int(n / p); 
                    count+=1; 
                total *=(count + 1); 

    return total; 


# Driver Code 
n = 24; 
print(divCount(n)); 

# This code is contributed by mits
```

Is the task doable without a computer, in reasonable time?

If so, what's the "magic" trick?

Comment: See also: [Highly composite number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HighlyCompositeNumber.html)

Comment: It wouldn't be a good Project Euler task if it was feasibly solvable with pencil and paper ...

Comment: What is the problem if you simply use the algorithm to calculate the number of divisors for an increasing (that keeps on increasing) $n$ in $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ and just compare it with the number of divisors you need so that it stops at the first occurrence?

Comment: i just want to know if there is a way our ancestors could have tackled this problem in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: One idea would be to try and find the smallest value of $n$ with $500$ divisors, or at least an upper bound. The problem is that this is probably nowhere close to the actual solution, since the factor of $n+1$ could potentially increase the number of divisors by one or two orders of magnitude. Since there's basically no relation between $d(n)$ and $d(n+1)$, you can't expect to be able to bound $d(n(n+1))=d(n)d(n+1)$ in an easy way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this problem can be solved without computers.
If $T(n)$ is the n-th triangular number, then we know that
$$T(n)=1+2+3+...+n=\sum^n_{i=1}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Let’s assume that we know the prime factorizations of both $n$ and $n+1$, and we’ll write

$$n=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}p_3^{e_3}...p_s^{e_s}\text{  and  }n+1=q_1^{f_1}q_2^{f_2}q_3^{f_3}...q_t^{f_t}$$
Notice that $n$ and $n+1$ cannot share any prime factors (as they are consecutive numbers), and so we know that all the $p_i$ and $q_i$ are distinct primes. Also, one and only one of $n$ and $n+1$ are divisible by $2$. The exponents $e_i$ and $f_i$ are therefore the only things we really need to consider in order to determine the number of divisors of $T(n)$. The fact that $T(n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ means that we’ll need to neglect a single power of two in the factorization of $n$ or $n+1$ (remember, only one is even). Let’s assume, without loss of generality, that $n$ is even and that $p_1=2$. Then, some quick combinatorics tell us that the total number of factors of $T(n)$ will be
$$(e_1+1)(e_2+1)...(e_s+1)(f_1+1)(f_2+1)...(f_t+1)=e_1\Pi^s_{i=2}(e_i+1)\Pi^t_{i=1}(f_i+1)$$

Even better, as we’re increasing our triangular numbers looking for the first one to satisfy the property in question, we only need to calculate the factorization of $n+1$ (as we already know that factorization of $n$, as it was previously $n+1$). This should decrease the run time substantially.

Comment: That formula will probably come in handy, but I think you're underestimating how much work is left to do. You don't even hit 200 divisors for the first 100,000 integers, and factoring a 4 digit number, let alone a 5 digit one, is hard enough to do for just one integer.

Comment: @JackM Are you sure? The smallest $n$ for which $T(n)$ has more than $500$ divisors is far below $10^5$.

Comment: Could someone explain a bit the combinatorics that are used here?